# Life span of JNI C++ heap in an Android app

Tags: android, java-native-interface, heap-memory

I'm in the process of re-architecting our Android app.  It is a complex app that consists of many Activities.  The main Activity loads a JNI native library.  This library allocates a number of structures on the C++ heap.

If the app is down in some subActivity and the main Activity gets stopped and unloaded due to low memory, what happens to the memory on the C++ heap?  Does this persist as long as the application process is running or can it somehow get deallocated when the Activity that loaded the library goes away?

I guess I have a similar question about a global C variable in the library.  Will it persist for the life of the whole process?

Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't find a definite answer in the documentation, yet, but I can tell you out of experience that long-running operations in native code survive the end of the Activity that started it. So there is no direct dependency on the Activity. For that purpose there is an NDK extension available that lets native code hook into the activity life cycle. After all: one app, one process

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I guess I'll just go ahead and assume the JNI storage persists as long as the process and hope for the best.